# program that counts blanks, tabs, and newlines

Tags: c, tabs, newline

I'm reading **The C Programming Language**. Here is a question which is saying *Write a program to count blanks, tabs, and newlines*. Now I can use **\n** for newlines and **\t** for tabs, but I am hearing first time about blanks! What it really mean by blanks? For the newlines and tabs, I have compiled following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*  program to count blanks, tabs, and newlines */
main (){
    long blanks, tabs, newlines, input;

    blanks = 0;
    tabs = 0;
    newlines = 0;
    input = 0;
    while ((input = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (input == '\n')
            ++newlines;
        else if (input == '\t')
            ++tabs;

    printf("Total newlines: %ld\nTotal Tabs: %ld", newlines, tabs);
}
```

Comment: A blank is usually just a space character (' ').

Comment: blanks are literally represented by " " in C

Comment: squiguy, " " denotes a null terminated character array.  You meant ' '.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

blanks = spaces (`' '`)

Though your code is working I strongly suggest adding `{ }` for the body of the while loop.

Comment: Adding noise like unnecessary braces is bad practice.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it noise when it's clarifying, as it is in this case.  While technically they're not necessary here, I would put them in every time for clarity.

Comment: @JerryCoffin bad practice? I think it's more hard for a beginner to understand WHEN he can omit braces than to use them always. Moreover it makes code more clear for any "average programmer" so it SHOULD BE USED by everyone to make our code more understandable.

Comment: @Adriano: yes, that's why I said it was a bad advice.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I've been a beginner in more different languages, almost more times than I can count. Understanding beats rote learning *every* time (and there **no** point in braces in a situation like this if you understand what you're dealing with at all).

Comment: @JerryCoffin you're not the point. the point is the average programmer.

Comment: @Jerry: and the avg. programmer will happily add an indented line after those `if`s.... yes, it's a dumb thing to do. but it will happen. coding standards are for the average guys. If you're a pro (and with 132k rep I'm sure you are), and if it makes sense, you're free to bend the rules provided that no beginners will touch your code. just don't force your style to others.

Comment: Who said anything about indentation being "dumb"? If you'll look back, *you* were the one who started out trying to enforce your style on others.

Comment: @Adriano: the question is whether you try to mentor people to become as good as (or better than) you are, or do you teach down to them, trying to keep them from being as good as possible? I think people should be given the benefit of all possible doubt; don't believe they have any less potential than yourself unless they force you to.

Comment: @JerryCoffin it's not just good wishes. Someone (I just feel lazy to search for reference now) did a lot of studies about this topic (and if open brace should be put on its own line). Results are more or less that: 1) "most of people feel more comfortable with unneeded braces" and 2) if you're used to do not use them you do not feel uncomfortable (= you do not misunderstand the code) when you see them. Then, I think, to use them won't hurt anyone but to do not use  them will make your code less readable for a lot of people.

Comment: @JerryCoffin so I use them and (yes...holy war LOL) I put { on its own line (when I do not have to follow an existing coding guide-line). Moreover I suggest people to use them for the same reason: someone else will read that code and _probably_ they'll find it more easy to understand.

Comment: @Adriano: Most studies I've seen that found unnecessary braces useful were done by people who clearly had pre-existing biases, and (often explicitly) set out to confirm those biases. The best I've seen from the few that weren't obviously biased was that people *can* learn to ignore the noise fairly easily, and they don't hurt people's reading/understanding *too* much (but that they do make reading slower, and misunderstanding a little more common anyway).

Comment: "Who said anything about indentation being "dumb"?" I certainly didn't. I just said if you don't have the braces there people will still add indented lines (again, maybe not you, but another developer who is not used to your style), but that line is not going to do what they expect - be part of the loop. People do make mistakes and braces can help preventing such stupid mistakes. And that's why must style guides suggest/force you to use those braces. If you have your own style, again, that's fine. But saying that using those braces is *bad practice* is quite *stupid*.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Each study is artifacted by people that did it but if most of them come to the same result then we could assert they're good enough. Moreover I agree with Karoly, if braces can prevent stupid mistakes then they're always welcome (and if they make the reading slower...good, I'll think better to what I'm reading).

Comment: @Adriano: You seem to be (intentionally?) ignoring the "and misunderstanding is a little more common anyway" part.

Comment: @JerryCoffin LOL no not intentionally I just don't agree. Actually the reason to use them or not is to make misunderstanding less common. There are some answers about this on programmers.stackexchange but I found nothing with valuable citations. Now I think that if most of the (modern) coding guidelines I saw ask **to use** braces even when unneeded (with the only exception of an unnested single line statement) then their sources could be a good start point. I'm pretty lazy for to search but...

Comment: @JerryCoffin but I'm talking about _programmers_ not _tools_. Of course I do not want to put extra braces for `while (IsEnabled) DoSomething();` but I would do if the body will be "indented" again.

Comment: @Adriano: I've looked for that. Most of the others seem to point to MISRA, but MISRA's "source" seems to be "because we think it's a good idea." Also see pages 7 and 10 of Les Hatton's critique though. He shows this rule as the sixth "noisiest" (i.e., most likely to be a false positive) of all ~150 in MISRA-C -- and well into the range where attempting to fix the "error" is more likely to introduce an error than fix anything.

Comment: @JerryCoffin anyway nice link, I'll take time to read it well!

Answer (score 0):

A blank is simply a space, most of the time. You should probably look into the `isblank()` function to help with classification.

Comment: Never heard of `isblank`; perhaps you meant `isspace`? You'd also need to be careful with ordering using this, as it'll say that new-lines and tabs are both "space".

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure they mean the space character ' '.

See here for the ASCII codes:

http://www.asciitable.com/

also 0x13 is carriage return, may want to look for that?  Newlines are not actually that simple depending on how the file is formatted:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

And like others have said, you may want to consider using functions from

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
printf("Type and Press Enter. CTRL-Z for EOF:\n");
int c;
int b = 0;
int t = 0;
int nl = 0;

while((c = getchar())!=EOF){

    putchar(c);
    if(c=='\t')
        ++t;

    if(c==' ')
        ++b;
    if(c=='\n')
        ++nl

}

printf("\n%d and %d\n",b,t,nl);


return 0;
```

}

You've added a else if which is not required here since we need to know all the 3 values.

Answer (score 0):

please find the code below this will get solution to your complete question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Count blank, tabs, and new lines */

main ()
{
    long c, b, t, l;    /* c for characters, b for blanks, t for tabs, l for lines */

    b = 0;
    t = 0;
    l = 0;

    while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF )
    {

        if ( c == '\n')
        ++l;
        if ( c == '\t')
        ++t;
        if ( c == ' ')
        ++b;
    }

    printf ("\n No of blanks : %d \n", b);
    printf ("\n No of tabs : %d \n", t);
    printf ("\n No lines in input: %d \n", l);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think blanks are new line followed by new line

```
        #include<stdio.h>
        int main()
        {
            int c,nl,nb,nt;
            nl = 0;
            nb = 0;
            nt = 0;
            int flag =1;

            while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
                if(c == '\n')
                {
                    ++nl;
                    if(flag)
                    ++nb;
                    flag = 1;  
                }
                else
                flag = 0;     

                if(c == '\t')
                ++nt;     
            }
            printf("lines : %d, tabs: %d, blanks: %d", nl, nt, nb);     

            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer -- benefited from other users' contributions -- uses only the material taught up to Exercise 1-8.  When Ctrl+z is pressed (I used Windows DOS), the program jumps to printf statements, prints answers, then exits to DOS prompt.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Exercise 1-8.  Write a program to count blanks, tabs, and newlines. */
int main()
{
    int bl, tb, nl, c;

    bl = 0;
    tb = 0;
    nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ')
            ++bl;
        if (c == '\t');
            ++tb;
        if (c == '\n');
            ++nl;
        }
    printf("Total blanks: %d\n", bl);
    printf("Total tabs: %d\n", tb);
    printf("Total newlines: %d\n", nl);
}
```

When you hit Enter key 5 times, press Spacebar 2 times, hit Tab key 4 times, then press Ctrl+z, you will get

Total blanks: 2
Total tabs: 4
Total newlines: 5

then DOS prompt.

Answer (score 0):

the solution I think is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
    int c, nl, nt, nb;

    nl = 0;
    nt = 0;
    nb = 0;


    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;

        if (c == '\t')
            ++nt;

        if (c == ' ')
            ++nb;
        }    

    printf("Blanks: %d\nNewlines: %d\nTabs: %d\n", nl, nt, nb);  }
```